# My css file is too big because url-loader is inserting a .jpg code into the .css file - How can I config webpack so it points towards the img?

Tags: css, webpack

I'm finishing an online course about some web dev tools.

In the course, somehow, the instructor doesn't run into a problem with webpack while using a .jpg url in the .css. After searching on StackOverflow and Google I've managed to find the answer in using the [url-loader webpack plugin](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/).

This worked fine while I was running a local dev environment.
However, when I built the website for deployment, the .css file was sized in 200kb. After running the file through a [beautifier](https://www.freeformatter.com/css-beautifier.html), I've found that it was because of the .jpg code being injected into the .css. After deleting that portion, the file size dropped down to less than 16kb.

How can I configure my webpack so when it builds, it replaces the inserted .jpg to a url pointing towards the actual image file?

Here are:

- The repo: https://github.com/sethalberdier/fictional-travel-site
- The folder containing the [huge css file](https://github.com/sethalberdier/fictional-travel-site/blob/master/docs/styles.2e8502f002390d735067.css) (and also the one that is live): https://github.com/sethalberdier/fictional-travel-site/tree/master/docs
- The code bits that matter, imo:

css:

```
    @mixin atLarge {
        background: url('/app/assets/images/testimonials-bg.jpg') top center;
    }
```

inside webpack.config I have this rule for the exports module:

```
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader',
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [`url-loader` docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/), it seems like you need to specify a `limit` in your webpack config file. For instance:

```js
{
  loader: 'url-loader',
  options: {
    limit: 8192
  }
}
```

If you want `url-loader` to never transform images into base64 strings, specify `{limit: false}` or use [`file-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) instead.

Comment: Thanks!

Indeed, what I was looking for was the file-loader.

What I did was pushing different rules for the dev environment and for the build environment.

When the limit for url-loader is crossed, it acts like file-loader, so I've added the `limit:false` to the build rule.
Then I ran into a 'public path' problem. This was easily solved by setting the public path directly to an empty string.